# How to customize a virtual keyboard in Windows Phone 8.1 and its related controls?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have two questions on a related problem. I combine them in one thread because I think separating them may result in dilutions. Here are the two problems:

1. Can I add a NEXT button (looks like an arrow) instead of an ENTER button normally, and, if yes, how can I do that?
2. How can I make a 'float' TextBox that goesup with the virtual keyboard when
   I tap to TextBox (i.e. it looks like a 'chat space' of OTT apps, where we make the content to send, which always floats with the virtual keyboard and on the top of the keyboard)?

I really need your help; please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answers:

1. You cannot customize the virtual keyboard.
2. you can move the textbox by setting margin in the InputPane(Showing & Hiding) events.

Hope that helps.